# Calculate login duration by month

Tags: python, pandas

This is my initial dataframe:

| Index | ID | Event | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Login | 10.03.2023 12:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 1 | Logout | 05.04.2023 12:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2 | Login | 20.04.2023 12:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 2 | Logout | 22.04.2023 12:00:00.000 |
| 5 | 1 | Login | 20.05.2023 12:00:00.000 |
| 6 | 1 | Login | 21.05.2023 12:00:00.000 |
| 7 | 1 | Logout | 22.05.2023 12:00:00.000 |
| 8 | 1 | Logout | 25.05.2023 12:00:00.000 |

How do I get the following result in pandas?

| ID | TimeInDays | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | March |
| 1 | 5 | April |
| 1 | 6 | May |
| 2 | 2 | April |

Do I firstly have to split it into a login and a logout dataframe and then joining it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom function to split the months:

```
def split_months(start, end):
    return (pd.Series([start, end, *pd.date_range(start, end, freq='M')])
              .drop_duplicates().sort_values(ignore_index=True)
              .to_frame(name='date')
              .assign(TimeInDays=lambda d: d['date'].diff(),
                      Month=lambda d: d.pop('date').dt.month_name()
                     )
              .iloc[1:]
           )

tmp = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Datetime'])

out = (tmp
  .groupby(['ID', df['Event'].eq('Login').cumsum()])
  .apply(lambda g: split_months(g['Datetime'].min(), g['Datetime'].max()))
  .reset_index('ID')
)
```

*NB. if you have several years, you might want to use `Month=lambda d: d.pop('date').dt.to_period('M')` to avoid ambiguity. If you want an integer for the number of days, use `TimeInDays=lambda d: d['date'].diff().dt.days`.*

Output:

```
   ID TimeInDays  Month
0   1    21 days  March
1   1     5 days  April
2   1     4 days    May
3   2     2 days  April
```