# Breakdown of time period (duration) to month/year

Tags: python, pandas

My initial dataframe looks as follows:

| ID | Start | End | DurationDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-20 12:00:00.000 | 2023-06-03 12:00:00.000 | 14 |
| 2 | 2023-05-20 12:00:00.000 | 2023-05-23 12:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-06-01 12:00:00.000 | 2023-06-03 12:00:00.000 | 2 |

How to get from this to a dataframe like the following? The problem is, there are quite a low of rows (millions). Therefor performance is quite important.

| ID | Year | Month | DurationDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023 | May | 11 |
| 2 | 2023 | May | 3 |
| 1 | 2023 | June | 5 |

**Update:** Please note, there could be more than one month to break. Example: 2023-02-20 (February) and 2023-12-18 (December)

Comment: how do you convert 14 to 11? and 2 to 5? Please clarify the logic

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one month to break. Example: 2023-05-20 (May) and 2023-07-18 (July)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that there is more than one month to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jezrael's approach is on the right track, but probably unrealistic for a large DataFrame as it requires to repeat the rows by days/hours (thus creating an intermediate with tens or hundreds of millions of rows).

Instead, it seems more reasonable to use pandas' [`Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html) as unit to repeat rows.

In short, this breaks the rows by period at their boundaries using [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and increments the periods with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html), gets the boundaries with [`start_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.start_time.html)/[`end_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.end_time.html), finally [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) to add the duration per period.

I voluntarily added several intermediate variables to make it easier to understand the code, but if needed many steps could be combined into one to avoid creating too many intermediate columns.

```
df[['Start', 'End']] = df[['Start', 'End']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

period = 'M'

out = (df.assign(start=df['Start'].dt.to_period(period),
                 end=df['End'].dt.to_period(period),
                 diff=lambda d: d['end'].sub(d['start']).apply(lambda x: x.n))
         .loc[lambda d: d.index.repeat(d['diff']+1)]
         .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),
                 Start=lambda d: d['Start'].mask(d.index.duplicated(), d['start'].add(d['n']).dt.start_time),
                 End=lambda d: d['End'].mask(d.index.duplicated(keep='last'), d['end'].add(d['n']).dt.start_time),
                 DurationDays=lambda d: d['End'].sub(d['Start']),
                 Year=lambda d: d['Start'].dt.year,
                 Month=lambda d: d['Start'].dt.month_name(),
                )
        .groupby(['ID', 'Year', 'Month'], as_index=False, sort=False)
       ['DurationDays'].sum()
      )
```

Output:

```
   ID  Year Month     DurationDays
0   1  2023   May 11 days 12:00:00
1   1  2023  June  4 days 12:00:00
2   2  2023   May  3 days 00:00:00
```

Intermediate before the `groupby.sum`:

```
   ID               Start                 End     DurationDays    start      end  diff  n  Year Month
0   1 2023-05-20 12:00:00 2023-06-01 00:00:00 11 days 12:00:00  2023-05  2023-06     1  0  2023   May
0   1 2023-06-01 00:00:00 2023-06-03 12:00:00  2 days 12:00:00  2023-05  2023-06     1  1  2023  June
1   2 2023-05-20 12:00:00 2023-05-23 12:00:00  3 days 00:00:00  2023-05  2023-05     0  0  2023   May
2   1 2023-06-01 12:00:00 2023-06-03 12:00:00  2 days 00:00:00  2023-06  2023-06     0  0  2023  June
```

##### generalization

For a more generic method that you can use with any period (provided you have enough resources):

```
df[['Start', 'End']] = df[['Start', 'End']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

period = 'Y'

out = (df.assign(Period=df['Start'].dt.to_period(period),
                 end=df['End'].dt.to_period(period),
                 diff=lambda d: d['end'].sub(d['Period']).apply(lambda x: x.n))
         .loc[lambda d: d.index.repeat(d['diff']+1)]
         .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),
                 Start=lambda d: d['Start'].mask(d.index.duplicated(), d['Period'].add(d['n']).dt.start_time),
                 End=lambda d: d['End'].mask(d.index.duplicated(keep='last'), d['end'].add(d['n']).dt.start_time),
                 DurationDays=lambda d: d['End'].sub(d['Start']),
                )
        .groupby(['ID', 'Period'], as_index=False, sort=False)
       ['DurationDays'].sum()
      )
```

Output for `period = 'Y'`:

```
   ID Period DurationDays
0   1   2023      16 days
1   2   2023       3 days
```

Output for `period = 'M'`:

```
   ID   Period DurationDays
0   1  2023-05      14 days
1   2  2023-05       3 days
2   1  2023-06       2 days
```

Answer (score 1):

First idea is repeat rows by difference of `End/Start` columns in days and count number of rows per `ID/Year/Month` by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df[['Start','End']] = df[['Start','End']].apply(pd.to_datetime)


df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['End'].sub(df['Start']).dt.days)]

s = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')
df['Date'] = df['Start'].add(s)

df = (df.groupby(['ID', df['Date'].dt.year.rename('Year'),
                       df['Date'].dt.month_name().rename('Month')], sort=False)
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='DurationDays'))
print (df)
   ID  Year Month  DurationDays
0   1  2023   May            12
1   1  2023  June             4
2   2  2023   May             3
```

For better precision is possible use hours instead days:

```
df[['Start','End']] = df[['Start','End']].apply(pd.to_datetime)


df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['End'].sub(df['Start']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600))]

s = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='h')
df['Start'] = df['Start'].add(s)

df = (df.assign(Year=df['Start'].dt.year,
                Month=df['Start'].dt.month_name())
          .groupby(['ID', 'Year','Month'], sort=False)
          .size()
          .div(24)
          .reset_index(name='DurationDays'))
print (df)
   ID  Year Month  DurationDays
0   1  2023   May          11.5
1   1  2023  June           4.5
2   2  2023   May           3.0
```

Comment: I get the following ValueError for the first line: 'repeats may not contain negative values'. Any ideas?

Comment: @question12 - It means `End` is lower like `Start` datetime.

Comment: @question12 - for check use `print (df[df['End'].sub(df['Start']).dt.days.lt(0)])`

Comment: Yes I have already checked. With your print I get 'Empty DataFrame' and 'Index: []'

Comment: @question12 - hmmm, also return empty dataframe `print (df['End'].sub(df['Start']).dt.total_seconds().lt(0))` ?

Comment: Okay, there have been NaN values. I think this was the reason for it. At the current time I get no output with your print-statement of your solution. But I think it is caused on my side.. I have to check :)

Comment: @question12 - hmm, so need repalce NaN in `End` by today?

Comment: @question12 - then use `df['End'] = df['End'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('now').normalize())`

Answer (score 1):

You can [`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html) your DataFrame then use [`split_months`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76456321/16120011) (*slightly adjusted*) :

```
tmp = (
    pd.lreshape(df, {'Datetime': ['Start', 'End']})
        .sort_values(by=['ID', 'Datetime'])
)

out = (
    tmp.groupby(['ID']).apply(
        lambda g: split_months(g['Datetime'].min(), g['Datetime'].max())
    ).reset_index('ID')
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   ID Month  Year  DurationDays
1   1   May  2023         11.00
2   1  June  2023          3.00 # <-- needs to be fixed (it is `2+3`)
1   2   May  2023          3.00
```